# Нужно найти ключ по значению. JSON. Python

Tags: python, json

`{ "2022-01-01": "weekend", "2022-01-02": "weekend", "2022-01-03": "holiday weekend", "2022-01-04": "holiday weekend", "2022-01-05": "holiday weekend", "2022-01-06": "holiday weekend", "2022-01-07": "holiday weekend", "2022-01-08": "weekend", "2022-01-09": "weekend", "2022-01-10": "workday", "2022-01-11": "workday", "2022-01-12": "workday", "2022-01-13": "workday" }`

Мне надо по значению вывести дату. В данном случае из значений "holiday weekend". Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас json-нина для начала следует конвертнуть ее в словарь python.

```
import json

d = json.load(#your json)
print(type(d))
```

Если все сделано верно в консоли cпринтится class 'dict' и если я правильно понял условие вашей задачи:

```
for key,value in d.items():
  if value == 'holiday weekend':
     print('key:',key)
```